# Sencha Architect - events stopped working after domain renamed - need troubleshooting steps

Tags: extjs, sencha-architect

Sencha Touch 2.3, using SA, built an app based on the template, "Login/Register" - which uses Controllers and References. 
In extending the app, there had been some behaviour/caching issues so, in trying to fix, the Domain got reset/renamed to "MyApp" I think because I removed a target web folder under htdocs (at least I didn't rename the application.name to MyApp).
I renamed it back to its original on the Application node.
When I rebuilt the app (Build web app) none of the events work. e.g. Login Button wont launch Login form.

I checked the files which are being loaded are actually the current ones.
On doing a

```
 grep -r "MyApp" *
```

on my application sources folder I see loads of files containing "MyApp" and conclude this is a standard value and that part of building an app does some search/replace?

When I turn on debug at the browser I can see the code in the Controller Action for the button is not being called (there is some console.log stuff there which should show up).

I've tried App refresh and the log output shows no errors only [INF].

My main question is this, how do I trace a problem when an event is clearly no longer firing? Is there a troubleshooting checklist to trace this?
Or are there some additional caches which can be cleared to reset?

Many thanks in advance

Kevin
PS. I tried also in Safari, its not the browser I guess.

Answer (score 0):

The problem turned out to be that not only did the application loose its name and reverted to MyApp, the Controller had been dropped (as did views, models and stores).
Once the Controller was added back to the Application then the Events would work again.